# Deleting/removing data in a many-to-many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
#The various models
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :competition_teams
  has_many :competitions, through: :competition_teams
end

class Competition < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :competition_teams
  has_many :teams, through: :competition_teams
end

class CompetitionTeam < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :competition
end

#The form I'm using to add teams to the competition

= semantic_form_for @competition do |f|
  = f.inputs :name do
     = f.input :teams, as: :select, collection: current_user.teams.select{|t| !@competition.teams.include?(t)}
  = f.actions do
    = f.action :submit, as: :button

#Competition update action, used to add teams

def update
  @competition = Competition.find(params[:id])
  teams = competition_params[:team_ids] + @competition.teams.pluck(:id)
  team = Team.find(competition_params[:team_ids][1])

  if team.users.pluck(:id).include?(current_user.id) && @competition.update_attribute(:team_ids, teams)
    redirect_to @competition
  end
end
```

So what I want to do is to create a button (or a link) that allows a user to remove their team from the competition. Should this be done with a custom action or a form of some sort?
I really have no idea where to go from here, so any help is very appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, a `form_for` will make a post request and goes to the `create` action if the object is a new object, and to the `update` action if the object is already in the db. What you want to have it do is make a request to the `delete` action where you will be deleting the team from the competition. You should get the @competition_team object first.

```
@competition_team = CompetitionTeam.new
```

then

```
= semantic_form_for @competition_team, method: 'delete' do |f|
```

Then in your competition_team controller, create your destroy action along with your code to delete the team from the competition.

```
def destroy
   #your code
end
```

Also, make sure to define the destroy action in your route.

Comment: So I should create a controller for competition_teams, which will serve only one purpose, deleting CompetitionTeams. I wanted to avoid that, but it makes everything a lot easier. I could just use the destroy action in the Competition controller to do the same thing, but I guess it's better to do it like this. Thank you so very much!
It's also kind of hard to get the @team object, since I have no team_id to get it. The page Im viewing and want to edit it from is 'competitions/:id'.

Comment: It wouldn't make sense to create it in the Competition controller because that's where you would create the destroy action to destroy the competition. It will be confusing with that approach.